# Drag event with Hammer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, hammer.js

Here is my js where i already did a swipeleft and swiperight events in order to show a toolbar on the left. (it is for a smartphone app, with touch events)
I wanted to add the drag event on it, to keep control on the bar (like on menu bar of Facebook, Tinder..

Do you know how i can do it ?

```
$(function(){

    var page = document.getElementById("page");
    var sidebar = 0;

    Hammer(page).on("swipeleft", function(e) { 
        if (!sidebar){
            return true;
        }
          $(page).animate({left: "-=300"}, 500);
          sidebar = 0;  
    });

    Hammer(page).on("swiperight", function(e) {
        if (sidebar){
            return true;
        }
          $(page).animate({left: "+=300"}, 500) ;
          sidebar=1; 
    });
})
```

I already tried this but it doesn't recognize drag and e.gesture.direction...

```
    Hammer(page).on("drag", function(e) {
            if ( e.gesture.direction === "right" && !sidebar){
                $(page).animate({left : e.gesture.deltaX + "px"}, 0);
            }
   });
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to say hello :) i didn't succeed to edit ...

Answer (score 2):

The event is called `pan` not `drag`. See [the docs](http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-pan/).

```
Hammer(page).on("panright", function(e) {
         if (!sidebar){
             $(page).animate({left : e.gesture.deltaX + "px"}, 0);
         }
});
```

Comment: ok thank you, now chrome console says : Cannot read property 'deltaX' of undefined

Comment: The problem is that I don't really know what exactly you want to animate and how. Try using `e.deltaX` instead of `e.gesture.deltaX`.

Comment: Actually it used to be called "dragleft and dragright" in version 1 of HammerJS... those Recongnizers were deprecated in v2 of HammerJS.  It's now "panleft and panright".

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it! You were right, **@Cristy** :)

Here is the working answer:

```
$(function(){

    var page = document.getElementById("page");
    var sidebar = 0;

    Hammer(page).on("swipeleft", function(e) { 
        if (!sidebar){
            return true;
        }
          $(page).animate({left: "-=300"}, 500);
          sidebar = 0;  
    });
    Hammer(page).on("panleft", function(e) {
         if (!sidebar){
             $(page).animate({left : e.deltaX + "px"}, 0);
         }
    });

    Hammer(page).on("swiperight", function(e) {
        if (sidebar){
            return true;
        }
          $(page).animate({left: "+=300"}, 500) ;
          sidebar=1; 
    });

    Hammer(page).on("panright", function(e) {
         if (!sidebar){
             $(page).animate({left : e.deltaX + "px"}, 0);
         }
});
})
```